# How to get property_id in Google Analytics Data API (GA4) using Python?

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I need to get a list with all 'Analytics accounts', I also need all property_id in Google Analytics that each 'Analytics accounts' contains.

When I used the Google Analytics API V3 (Universal Analytics) to get the view_id, I followed the guide described in the link below:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/installed-py -> the line of code:

```
accounts = service.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()
```

but when I use the API (GA4) I have to use the instructions given in the link below:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts/list

For this case, I tried to use the below script to get property id, and get this message:

```
import requests
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account


url = 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/accountSummaries'
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = r'C:/.../cogent-precinct.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

params = {'pageSize': 50}
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
print(data)


{'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie, or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.', 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}
```

The json file I'm using in the KEY_FILE_LOCATION variable is the json generated during the 'Service account' creation process in https://console.cloud.google.com, when creating the key which I saved to the json file, and I think the problem is in the .json file.

The documentation says that I should use pageToken, but I don't understand how I can generate it.

What am I doing wrong, maybe something needs to be changed in the script, also what jason file do I need to use to get access and how do I generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your credentials:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'location of your client_secrets.json'
```

See for getting property_ids: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/management-ua-to-ga4

This is the code:

```
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient

def list_account_summaries(transport: str = None) -> None:
    """
    Prints summaries of all accounts accessible by the caller.

    Args:
        transport(str): The transport to use. For example, "grpc"
            or "rest". If set to None, a transport is chosen automatically.
    """
    client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(transport=transport)
    results = client.list_account_summaries()

    print("Result:")
    for account_summary in results:
        print("-- Account --")
        print(f"Resource name: {account_summary.name}")
        print(f"Account name: {account_summary.account}")
        print(f"Display name: {account_summary.display_name}")
        print()
        for property_summary in account_summary.property_summaries:
            print("-- Property --")
            print(f"Property resource name: {property_summary.property}")
            print(f"Property display name: {property_summary.display_name}")
            print()

# Account is UA; Property is GA4
list_account_summaries()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def acquire_new_oauth2_credentials(secrets_file):
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
if not os.path.exists("token.json"):
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(secrets_file, SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
else:
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
return creds

def load_oauth2_credentials(secrets_file):
credentials = None
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = acquire_new_oauth2_credentials(secrets_file)
return credentials


credentials = load_oauth2_credentials('client_secret.json')  # give it Oauth credentials

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
request = ListAccountSummariesRequest()
response = client.list_account_summaries(request)

properties_data={}

for account_summary in response.account_summaries:
    properties_data[account_summary.display_name]=[]
    for property_summary in account_summary.property_summaries:
        if 'GA4'.upper() in str(property_summary.display_name).upper():
            properties_data[account_summary.display_name].
            append(property_summary.property.split('/')[-1])

with open('properties_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(properties_data, json_file, indent=4)

print("Properties saved to 'properties_data.json' file.")
```

it will get the oauth generate refresh token use that token to get the credentails making a client , get the specified data in my case having only that property credentails which have 'ga4' in it and make a json file of the credentials.